# What can I do with badly cooked honeycomb?

Tags: candy

I've made a batch of honeycomb but I didn't quite get the temperature of the sugar right. Now it seems to have the consistency of toffee.

What can I do with this honeycomb? It would seem a bit of  a waste to just through it away...

Comment: I am not sure that everybody will recognize what "honeycomb" is, I had to look it up. And even without that, it would be better to post the recipe you followed just to know what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to dissolve the candy, and then boil it down again, foaming it with fresh baking soda when it hits the proper stage.  The thing is, the candy has already got the full level of baking soda reactants (either sodium carbonate or sodium oxide) from from the first cooking, which may contribute to some off flavors.

Instead, if it is enjoyable as is, I would suggest just eating it as a toffee like candy.

Otherwise, chalk it up to experience and watch the temperature more closely next time.

Answer (score 0):

Do the hokey pokey. Smack it into small pieces and mix with plain soft icecream, re-freeze, and the kids will love it

Answer (score 0):

I have a batch of gooey toffee now too.  So im just either enjoying it as is or adding bit or chunks of it to my coffee or ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with the failed honeycomb is smash it into small bits or even grind it up into very tiny almost to powder. Then I melt the chocolate and pour it over the bits and stir it well. You can pour it into moldes or make it into any shape you want. Big pieces, small bite size pieces, whatever you want it's still tasty I call it MY HONEYCOMB CRUNCH

Comment: Welcome! Your answer is a nice idea if the sugar is brittle, but the asker reports that theirs is like toffee, which would make smashing or grinding difficult or impossible. Can you [edit] your post and clarify?